# LARAVEL phone begins with 05 or 06 "preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I'm using LARAVEL 5.5, I want to test the regex to my phone number whether the number begins with 05 or 06 and number length should be 9.

per example, if the number is 068852123 or 0522321485.

there is my code below :

```
'telephone_1' => 'required|regex:/(05)|(06)[0-9]{8}/',
```

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it start with 05 or 06 and the total length is 9, the [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/eAwI6c/1) pattern can be

```
^0[56][0-9]{7}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` start of the string
- `0` a digit of zero
- `[56]` takes one digit from 5 or 6
- `[0-9]{7}` take 7 digits form 0 - 9
- `$` end of the string.

**PHP code:**

```
$phone_no = '068852123';
if (preg_match('/^0[56][0-9]{7}$/', $phone_no)) {
    echo 'Valid phone no';
} else {
    echo 'invalid phone no';
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, you're right the best solution is to take one digit from 5 or 6 after 0.